# How to get current text selection or document of Geany window into Python without creating plugin?

Tags: python, geany

I have Geany 1.25 installed in my system(Ubuntu 14.04).

I want to perform some text replacement operations on my currently opened document in Geany(both whole document & text selection) with python scripting, but I prefer not to make a complete plugin(as it is somewhat complex) for this.

Can anybody suggest an intermediate way like "External Tools" of Gedit ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can interact with your Python script via stdin and stdout, you could use the ["Send selection to"](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#sending-text-through-custom-commands) feature.

Some kind of little script is possible with plugin [GeanyMiniScript](http://plugins.geany.org/geanyminiscript.html) but it's without active maintainership for some time now so might not work.